# how to get weight or delta of current field collection item that is being computed

Tags: entities

Is it possible to get weight(order index) of multi field "field collection".This weight is needed inside computed field which is inside field collection.I tried the following but it returns empty

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $entity);    
$instance = field_read_instance('field_collection_item',$wrapper, 'bundle_name');
dpm($instance['widget']['weight']);
```

Here is the structure

**main_content**-contains field collection (multi value)
------**field collection(s)**-contains 1 text field and 1 computed field
------|----item 0
------|-------|-------computed_field <---here how to get weight of field collection item ie 0
------|----item 1
------|-------|-------computed_field <---here how to get weight of field collection item ie 1
------|----item 2
------|-------|-------computed_field
------|----item n
------|-------|-------computed_field

Answer (score 3):

I was searching in wrong path :( this is found at

http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!field_collection!field_collection.module/class/FieldCollectionItemEntity/7

code for getting delta is

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $entity);
$cur_delta=$wrapper->delta();
```

Comment: Thank you for referencing this method. Note that the "delta" method also works after using the function "field_collection_field_get_entity" which allows you to get the entity from the field collection. Cheers.